# How can I draw a cube with a depth buffer in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, depth-buffer, opengl-es-2.0

I've been trying to draw a cube without success using OpenGL ES 2.0 and a depth buffer.

Are there any examples of this available that I could compare against to see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example for a recent class, I created a sample application that draws a textured cube using both OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0, which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/CubeExample.zip).  Unfortunately, that application does not use a depth buffer for anything.

I created a more complex OpenGL ES 2.0 application that does use one [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ShaderExamples.zip), so you might be able to pull code from this one into the other to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I didn't re-check, but do you still have that (sorry) ugly front face culling hack in the cube example? Confused the heck out of me when combined with some choice mistakes and hacks of my own.

Comment: @fzwo - Yes, I do (at least for the OpenGL ES 1.1 implementation).  I never did sit down and figure out the correct way to handle the alternate windings of the indexed triangle strips I use to build the cube.  The front face culling switch was a suggestion from an Apple engineer as a quick fix, so I've left it in there.  Also, I still haven't corrected all the texture indices in this example.  If you have suggestions, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Brad: I've taken your cubes and use them (with attribution, of course) in the prototype of a strictly GLES2 3D program. They seem to render correctly for me (both with no culling, and with backface culling), and I've also tried and followed how you did the triangle indices, and that setup also looked right to me.

I don't have access to Xcode at the moment, so I can't really comment on your project right now.

Anyway, thank you for the iTunes U course - it's one of very, very few resources available for GLES2 beginners.

Comment: When I create a project from scratch and try to load shaders with GLProgram, they simply fail to load. Is there something subtle I have to do to properly include them in the project? If I check in the .app file, the .fsh and .vsh files are not present. Any ideas?

Comment: @sharvey - You need to make sure that Xcode treats your shader files as resources, not code to be compiled.  Make sure that the shaders are listed under the Copy Bundle Resources build phase in your target, and not the Compile Sources one.  That way, they will be copied into your application bundle and used at runtime.